# simplexml php extract data in a for loop

Tags: php, simplexml

Im running a query and getting a getting data of some 500 rows.

Among a field in the query im storing a xml string,i want to extract lastname from the xml data.
I tried the following but printing zero
I used simple xml

```
$sql ="select col1,col2,xml_col from table "
echo $sql;
$sql_resource= mysql_query($sql);
$downloads = $a->get_results($sql);
foreach($downloads  as $d)
{
   $col1 =$d->col1;
   $col2 =$d->col2;
   $posted_data = $d->posted_data;
   $xml=simplexml_load_string($posted_data);
   print_r($xml->your-name);
}
```

I want to extract lastname from the xml of multiple xml data
XML format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<posted_data>
<your-name>john</your-name>
<your-mname>dayton</your-mname>
<your-lname>haris</your-lname>
</posted_data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `-` in object, PHP do not like this. Use this instead:

```
print_r($xml->{your-name});
```

Or:

```
print_r($xml->posted_data->{your-name});
```